# Xamarin File Storage

Tags: file, xamarin

Question:

I know how to Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),  "SomeFile.txt");

But my question is when using emulator where does it store it or is it only in memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

on Android, files are stored in the file system within the emulator image.  You can use `adb` to access the files.

on iOS, the emulator file system is mapped onto the MacOS file system.  You can get the full file path in code and then just access the files from `Terminal` or `Finder`